# C# wpf question custom checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I just started getting deeper into C# and WPF design, so dont mind if I ask for some basics.

I am trying to port one of our internet applications to a c# application and having some difficulties.

I need 4 checkboxes which look like this. If you click them they should look like the second one.

http://frauneder.com/checkbox_example.jpg

I was able to do it with images which change on click but there I miss the ischecked property.

The second question:
I want to check/uncheck the checkboxes using the 1-4 keys on my keyboard. How do I do this?

Thanx very much in advance!

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure I fully understand your questions, but let me try. It all matters how deep you want to go here, too. There are many ways to skin this cat.

**1** - I think you're asking how to use the `IsChecked` property to influence the look of the `CheckBox`? The way to do this is re-template the `CheckBox` and use a trigger in the template. Something like this:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="_image" Source="Unchecked.jpg"/>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="_image" Property="Source" Value="Checked.jpg"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </CheckBox.Template>
</CheckBox>
```

There is more to consider here, but that should get you started.

**2** - You can use `InputBindings` to execute a command when some input is received by the control. So you can define a command that checks or unchecks the appropriate `CheckBox` based on the parameter passed to the command. Then you can do something like this:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="1" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.YourCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
    </CheckBox.InputBindings>
</CheckBox>
```

Again, there are many ways to solve your problems here. Hopefully this steers you in the right direction.